# Smooth GameObject Rotation

Tags: c#, unity

I want to rotate a 3D GameObject from 0 degrees to 180 degrees on the Z axis ***smoothly*** at a speed that I can define. How can I do this?

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from.rotation, to.rotation, Time.time * speed);` from is a GameObject at 180° and to is a GameObject at 0°. But that doesn't do what I want.

Comment: You should include this in your question, along with *what* does it do currently. In order to answer you question people need as many details as you can provide.

Comment: You are doing same thing again and again. Don't edit your question that evolves it into something completely different, you have been warned for this two times before by moderators!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option for your case would be to try an approach similar to the following. Just copy and paste the whole code in a new C# script in Unity and *assign the script to the object you want to rotate.*

Notice that the rotation is triggered by pressing "Space bar", but of course you can change that.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RotationLerping : MonoBehaviour {

    float rot_duration = 500F; //or the amount you find more suitable for the duration of the rotation
    float rot_speed = 0.25F; //or the amount you find more suitable for the rotation speed
    Quaternion final_rot;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Vector3 initial_rot = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        final_rot = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(initial_rot.x,initial_rot.y,180)); //here you choose the final rotation. Currently it is set to end up with the same X and Y rotation as the initial one, but with Z=180, as requested
    }

    IEnumerator rotateOBJ ()
    {
        float rot_elapsedTime = 0.0F;
        while (rot_elapsedTime  < rot_duration)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,final_rot,rot_elapsedTime);
            rot_elapsedTime  += Time.deltaTime*rot_speed;
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) StartCoroutine("rotateOBJ");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty basic implementation and should get you on the right path to how you would want to implement in your own project. There are many examples on rotation you can find but this is pretty straight forward.

```
Quaternion rotationMax;
void Start () {
    rotationMax = transform.rotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, transform.forward);
}
void Update () {
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotationMax, Time.deltaTime * 2);
}
```

if you are not fond of a slerp then you could also do a Rotate pretty easily like so. you could add a check if you need to make sure it is exactly 180 each completion.

```
float degrees = 180;
float speed = 30;

void Update () {
    if(transform.localEulerAngles.z<degrees)
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: I want to rotate the 3D GameObject from 0 degrees to 180 degrees **on the Z axis only**.